# Which one is correct? "I walk most places." or "I walk to most places."

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrase-meaning, expressions, idiomatic-language

Two people are talking:

**A: How do you get around?**

**B: I cycle or walk most places.**

The B's answer sounded different to me, because I think there should be a **"to"** after **"walk or cycle"** to sound correct. I mean it should be **"walk to a place"** or **"cycle to a place."**. On the internet, I saw sentences in both forms and got confused.

Really, which one is correct? Is it **"to walk a place"** or **"to walk to a  place"**.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would say "I cycle or walk **to** most places", but an American would probably leave out the 'to'. But of you are talking about one single place, **walk to a place** is correct and your other versions are not.

Comment: If you are visiting a number of towns and cities in England (for example) you might travel by train to each one and use your sentence B to describe how you travel *within* each place. London might be an exception! Otherwise @KateBunting is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are common usage and have the same meaning.

- "I walk to most places" is always correct.
- "I walk most places" is also common usage.

Both indicate that speaker walks to most destinations.  Depending on conversation context, both may imply that the speaker prefers to walk.  Although, if the context is that the speaker is discussing loss of a vehicle or has no money for the bus or train, it implies that the speaker as no choice but to walk.

As noted by @Kate Bunting above, dropping the "to" may be an American usage.